# Can the iPhone XS or iPhone X record screen at 1080p via QuickTime?

Tags: iphone, video, screen-capture, quicktime

I need to record some gameplay of my app at 1080p, and I am considering buying an iPhone XS or iPhone X to do so. I currently record the screen of my iPhone 7 via 
QuickTime for better quality, and the output is 750x1334, matching the resolution of the iPhone 7.

Before I commit to buying a new iPhone, I wanted to confirm whether I can record the screen of an iPhone X or XS via QuickTime at full 1080p. Anyone know of this is possible? Thank you.